# The probability of choosing a motorist

Tags: probability

a)from the given data we get

95 and male = 40 , 95 and female = 50

98 and male=20 , 98 and female=20

d and male = 60 , d and female = 10

Then the answer for a is $\frac{40}{200} = 0.2$

b) P(male|98) =$\frac{20}{40}=0.5$

For part c i do not know how can i figure it out[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate total motorist who serviced their car. $90$ bought U95 out of which $10%$ which is $9$ got serviced,  then $70$ bought diesel out of which $40%$ which is $28$ got serviced. And $40$ bought $40$ bought U98 and $30%$ which is $12$ got serviced.

So in all $49$ got servicing.

Comment: Thank you , i thought that the sentence serviced by the garage refers only to the diesel @jeea